# Getting error 'handleChange' is not defined

Tags: reactjs

handleChange function isnt executing and getting error that its undefined
and also how to use updayeLayout() from react-stackgrid libraray
link :- https://github.com/tsuyoshiwada/react-stack-grid

```
import StackGrid from "react-stack-grid";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TodoApp = () => {

const [state, setState] = useState(400);  


handleChange = () => {
    const newValue = 400;
    setState(newValue);
 this.grid.updateLayout();

};
         


return (
    <div className="container">
        <button onClick={handleChange}>Change </button>
        
        <StackGrid 
            columnWidth={200} duration={400} 
            gridRef={grid => this.grid = grid} 
        >
            <div key="key1" style={{height:`${state}px`,backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 1</div>
            <div key="key2" style={{height:`${state}px`,backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 2</div>
            <div key="key3" style={{height:"500px",backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 3</div>
            <div key="key4" style={{height:"800px",backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 2</div>
            <div key="key5" style={{height:"350px",backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 3</div>
            <div key="key6" style={{height:`${state}px`,backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 2</div>
            <div key="key7" style={{height:"300px",backgroundColor:'red'}}>Item 3</div>
        </StackGrid>
    </div>
    );

}


export default TodoApp;
```

**Error**

```
Line 9:5:  'handleChange' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: Typo, should be `const handleChange = () => {.....`, `handleChange` isn't declared. Voting to close.

Comment: Do you know how to use updateLayout() in it? it isnt updateing the whole layout
now its error is geeting that 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined`

Comment: What is `updateLayout`? There is no such thing in your code snippet. Also, functional components have no `this` that is defined.

Comment: i have updated it look

Comment: (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stack-grid) this is the api i'm tryng to use! Help me!

Comment: Sure thing, answered below. Please consider answer & explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

- `handleChange` isn't defined
- Functional components don't have a `this` to use, so setting/accessing the grid ref won't work

## Solution

Declare the `handleClick` callback and use a react ref (`useRef` hook) to get the grid's ref.

```
const TodoApp = () => {
  const gridRef = useRef(); // <-- (1) create a ref
  const [state, setState] = useState(400);

  const handleChange = () => {
    const newValue = 400;
    setState(newValue);
    gridRef.current.updateLayout(); // <-- (3) use ref
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button onClick={handleChange}>Change </button>

      <StackGrid
        columnWidth={200}
        duration={400}
        gridRef={(grid) => (gridRef.current = grid)} // <-- (2) assign ref
      >
        ...
      </StackGrid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit getting-error-handlechange-is-not-defined]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here you didn't defined `handleChange` so please replace

```
handleChange = () => {
    const newValue = 400;
    setState(newValue);
    this.grid.updateLayout();
}
```

};

with

```
const handleChange = () => {
    const newValue = 400;
    setState(newValue);
    this.grid.updateLayout();
}
```

};